# Compare histograms and display the result in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I’m trying to define three categories of ultrasound images:
Dense breast, fat breast, and undefined.

For this propose i´m using the histogram of gray level of each image:

- if the distribution of the histogram is close to the axis yy it´s a breast with dense tissue
- if the distribution of gray level it´s in the right side  means that we have a fatty breast.
- If the level of gray is homogeneously distributed means that we are facing an undefined case, it´s not dense and it´s not fatty.

My problem is how can I use the information of the histogram, how can I compare the histograms automatically with MATLAB, and say if it´s dense or fatty???

Any ideas ???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tryed The Euclidean distance d between two histograms, but didn´t work, Paul :((

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) measure:

[image: screenshot]

Skewness is zero when the histogram symmetrical. If the left hand tail is longer, skewness will be negative. If the right hand tail is longer, skewness will be positive.

Comment: Skewness can be a nice statistic, however it's a 3-point stat, so it's convergence is a *lot* slower than the mean and s.d.  It's also very sensitive to outliers.  You may find a percentile-based method to be more robust.  If you find that skewness isn't working well (which is very well might!), I would try a method that looked at the distance between three percentiles (eg: 25%, 50%, 75% or 5%, 50%, 95%) to see  if this gives you a metric that's more robust to noise and small samples.  You may also try censuring your data before calculating its skewness to limit the effect of outliers.

Comment: Now my problem is how to use skewness fuction in matlab to work on my images :(( every time i try to build a fuction i have errors...can somebody help again please!?

Comment: @DanielSimao: edit your question and post the code you have so far, along the with the error messages you are receiving

Comment: HI Amro that´s my code but how can I define 3 point statistics??i=imread('Image21.jpg');
I=rgb2gray(i);
original=(I);
S = skewness(imhist(original));

Comment: I mean if positive value = X for exemple, if negative value = Y, if not positive and not negative = Z....:((